# Grafana dashboard panel with custom time range

Tags: grafana, dashboard

I have a Grafana dashboard with a time range for "today so far"

```json
"time": {
    "from": "now/d",
    "to": "now"
 }
```

But I have a service that runs only between 4am and 5am every day for which I would like to plot some metrics in a panel on this dashboard. I'm trying to set the time range for that panel to 4am-5am of the current day so that it doesn't show a full 24 hour x-axis for data that only exists between 4am and 5am. If I were able to specify the time range for the panel using `From:` and `To:`, it would have looked something like this:

```json
"time": {
    "from": "now/d+4h",
    "to": "now/d-19h"
 }
```

But of course, you can't specify a time range like that for individual panels. You have to make use of the `Relative Time` and `Time Shift` values in [Query Options](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.1/panels/query-options/) for the panel but, for the life of me, I can't figure out how to represent the time range I want in relative time using those two values. It would seem that Grafana's documentation in this regard is sorely lacking; They only show a few very basic and specific examples, none of which helps me with this query.

Would anyone be able to set me straight here please?

For what it's worth, my data source for this Grafana dashboard is Prometheus but I don't think that is germane to this question.